# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setUsername')

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelId = "926668045068410913";
    const rulesChannel = "927464314707783771";
    const canvacord = require("canvacord")

    client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
        const welcomeCard = new canvacord.Welcomer
            .setUsername(member.user.username)
            .setDiscriminator(discriminator.user.username)
            .setAvatar(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png" }))
            .setColor("tittle", "#111111")
            .setColor("username-box", "#111111")
            .setColor("user-discriminator", "#111111")
            .setColor("message-box", "#111111")
            .setColor("boder", "#111111")
            .setColor("avatar", "#111111")
            .setbackgroung("https://i.imgur.com/WTQXVME.jpeg")
            .set(member.guild.memberCount)

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
        channel.send(welcomeCard);
    });
};
```

I want to fix the bug that happens when I use
`.setUsername(member.user.username)`.

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

What can I do?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: The code is trying to read the property `user`, belonging to `member`, but `member` is **null**. Double-check that `member` is effectively passed to your `guildMemberAdd` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use `setUsername` method on `canvacord.Welcomer` class not an object of this class try putting `()` after `canvacord.Welcomer` like this:

```js
const welcomeCard = new canvacord.Welcomer() // <- here
    .setUsername(member.user.username)
    // ... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new canvacord.Welcomer
```

That's not how you invoke a new class you missed a pair of brackets in that line. Change that line to

```
new canvacord.Welcomer()
```